# Getting a negative volume for polar double integral?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, polar-coordinates, advice

I am doing a math project where I am modeling a shape using a piecewise function. I am then using an online calculator to carry out double integration. However for the equation:

```
            r = 5cos⁡(2θ)-1, 2.85 ≤ r ≤ 4
```

I keep on getting a negative volume (see picture).
I have also plotted the region I am trying to find the of volume on Desmos, if that's helpful (see picture 2).
I really have no idea what to do and my math teacher could not offer any help.

[calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htH7h.png)

[graph (desmos)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Nyld.jpg)

Comment: You say "volume" but I see no picture or description of a three-dimensional object. I see a picture of two circles with two "ears" attached to the outside of one circle. Are you looking for the total area of the two "ears"? Or something else? Is there a third dimension you have not yet shown us?

Comment: I am trying to find the volume of the shape who’s polar domain is defined by those two “ears”. Sorry if I’m not explaining this correctly, but pretty much the first integration is to find those two “ears” bound by my curve and the bounds r=4 and r=2.85. Then the second integration is to find the volume.

Comment: There is no such thing as "the shape" whose "polar domain" is defined by the region of the two ears. You could support any number of different three-dimensional shapes above, below, or through those two regions, but up to this point you've given no clue about which of those infinite variety of shapes you want. It seems to me that the reason you are getting an unexpected answer is you have no idea even how to ask the question.

Comment: The only thing I can think to suggest in order to move forward is first to move back. Forget about how you find the volume for now; instead, try to explain why you are looking for a volume in the first place, and how you came to decide what volume you needed to find.

Comment: I’m sorry if I’m being completely stupid but I have gotten 0 help from this so I am slightly lost. I do not quite understand how there can be a variety of shapes from that region I selected. From the lectures I have watched on this, they always had one possible shape? Otherwise, if I have defined the bounds for the region, how could I ever control what volume I get, if there’s many possibilities? I do understand how this actual formula for double integration is derived, but I think I’m not understanding it’s application. If you don’t have time to explain, are there any resources you recommend?

Comment: Never mind, watched a few more videos and I’ve completely understood where I’ve gone wrong conceptually. Thank you for your help though; steered me to the right direction.